# Error: Unable to import 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python

Currently working on a flask project, but flask_sqlalchemy is not loading in the app.py file. The flask library, however, is loading.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

How does one solve this?

Comment: most likely you don't have flask_sqlalchemy installed. `pip install flask_sqlalchemy`

Comment: I have tried that multiple times, and it always shows as alredy installed.

Comment: Try reinstalling. Maybe also confirm that you're using the correct python executable to start your web app?

Comment: I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the library, but to no avail. The python executable should be correct because the webpage can be accessed when I run it, it just crashes whenever I use any form that works with sqlalchemy.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Make sure you have activated your environment before doing the pip install

Comment: I am not using a virtual environment, just running the files. I am not sure how virtual environments are activated.

Comment: @concerned_citizen what is the error appears when you're running the code?

Comment: @concerned_citizen - most likely you have more than one version of Python installed. For example if you're using an IDE it might point to a Python 3 install but your command line points to Python 2.  The best way to fix this is to learn about and use virtual environments: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if your user have permissions to execute this library. Try to import library from console and check output of command dir(SQLAlchemy())